# Change CSS of div when clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to change the background image of a div when a button outside of the div is selected?

e.g.

HTML

```
<div id="change"></div>

<div id="buttons">
   <button class="button1">this</button>
   <button class="button2">that</button>
   <button class="button3">there</button>
   <button class="button4">then</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#change{
  background-image: url("this.jpg")
}
```

Desired effect when clicking button 2 (same for each button; 3 = there.jpg, 4 = then.jpg)

```
#change{
  background-image: url("that.jpg")
}
```

Comment: `.css("background-image", ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javascript you can set the `backgroundImage`. Using jQuery you'd use `$.css('background-image');`

You could also use JS/jQuery to add a class to the element, and you can set the `background-image` in CSS for that class.

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',function() {
  document.getElementById('change').style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://futurism.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/neildegrassetyson.jpg)';
})
```

```css
#change {
  background: #eee;
  width: 600px;
  height: 375px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">button</button>
<div id="change"></div>
```

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',function() {
  document.getElementById('change').classList.add('bg');
})
```

```css
#change {
  background: #eee;
  width: 600px;
  height: 375px;
}
#change.bg {
  background-image: url(https://futurism.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/neildegrassetyson.jpg)
}
```

```html
<button id="button">button</button>
<div id="change"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this but it will require JavaScript:

Your HTML:

```
<div id="buttons">
  <button class="button1" onclick="changeBG('image1.jpg')">this</button>
  <button class="button2" onclick="changeBG('image2.jpg')">that</button>
  <button class="button3" onclick="changeBG('image3.jpg')">there</button>
  <button class="button4" onclick="changeBG('image4.jpg')">then</button>
</div>

<script>
  function changeBG(image) {
    var urlString = "url(" + image + ")";
    document.getElementById('change').style.backgroundImage = urlString;
  }
</script>
```

This is not the prettiest way to do this but it should accomplish getting you started.

Answer (score 1):

**This is what you need in jQuery :D**

```
$('#buttons button').on('click',function() {
    var val = $(this).text();
    $('#change').css('background-image','url('+val+'.jpg)');
});
```

put the script inside `$(document).ready(function() {`